# MS Access form: Mother combo box not showing correctly in table, but daughter combo is

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I set up two combo boxes, a mother and daughter.  Mother (one) controls the daughter (many).  Mother consists of 7 columns, I only need 2 to display correctly.  the first column is the Identifier column, the second column is the name.  Once the item in the mother combo is selected, the daughter is filtered to only show those associated names to the mother.

Everything works fine, but, when I look at the data in the table, the identifying number is in the name column where there should be a name. In the properties I have the following set up:

```
Tab Format:  Column Count 7
Column Width: 1;3;0;0;0;0;0  
Tab Data:  Bound Column 1
```

When I change this to 2, it puts the proper information into the table, but it breaks the link to the daughter - I see no information in the daughter combo box in the form.
Row source is basically a query from the table where this data is being retrieved.

Daughter cell has basically the same set up except in the Row source query, the associating ID column has code that goes something like:  `[Forms]![frm_Master]![cboMain]` - in the Criteria of the MainIDs column.  This column is the key column in the Mother table.

Forgive me - as I'm a newby at this I'm happy to work offline. I may have done this completely wrong, but, I don't think so, because most of it works except that one piece.

> Edit: The row source for the mother is as follows.

```
SELECT tbl_Main.MainIDs, tbl_Main.MainAccount, tbl_Main.Main_City, tbl_Main.Main_State, tbl_Main.Main_mgr, tbl_Main.MainE, tbl_Main.Main_Date FROM tbl_Main GROUP BY tbl_Main.MainIDs, tbl_Main.MainAccount, tbl_Main.Main_City, tbl_Main.Main_State, tbl_Main.Main_mgr, tbl_Main.MainE, tbl_Main.Main_Date ORDER BY tbl_Main.MainAccount;
```

Comment: Why would you save name instead of ID? Edit question to show SQL statement for RowSource. Usually the ID is bound column and it is set with 0 width because users normally don't need to see ID.

Comment: The row source for the mother is as follows:

Comment: SELECT tbl_Main.MainIDs, tbl_Main.MainAccount, tbl_Main.Main_City, tbl_Main.Main_State, tbl_Main.Main_mgr, tbl_Main.MainE, tbl_Main.Main_Date FROM tbl_Main GROUP BY tbl_Main.MainIDs, tbl_Main.MainAccount, tbl_Main.Main_City, tbl_Main.Main_State, tbl_Main.Main_mgr, tbl_Main.MainE, tbl_Main.Main_Date ORDER BY tbl_Main.MainAccount;

Comment: I didn't set it to 0 because I wanted to see the behavior if it isn't set to 0.  I had it set to 0 at first.

Comment: That info should be in question, not comment. Again why save name instead of ID? Why duplicate name in multiple tables?

Comment: It behaved all the same.  Whether set to 0 or not.

Comment: When bound column is 2 then you can try `[Forms]![frm_Master]![cboMain].Column(1)`. Here column(1) means index-1 that mean column two.

Comment: Ok!  Thanks, I’ll try it.

Comment: @Harun24HR - I tried setting the column bound to 2 in the mother and in the daughter adding .Column(1) - it threw an error.

Comment: Can you please show us some sample data and screenshots. Also where and how you using it?

Comment: I have a form that contains accounts information by ID number and the account site name.  This is a searchable combo box.  When the user selects an account - it affects the list of prescribers that is in another combo box.  Each account has any number of prescribers to choose from.

Comment: It's hard to explain because I go over the limit and I can't affix a picture here - I may not know how to do this.  Can we go to email?

Comment: Here is my goal:
two comboboxes cbo_accounts and cbo_prescribers.  Once a user selects the Account, that limits the prescribers selections.

In the table, I would like to see the accounts in text as opposed to a number.  I'd also like to see prescribers in text.

Comment: Control Src:  PrescriberAccount
accounts combobox draws from tbl_accounts:  here are the fields in the form RowSource:  AccountIDs, PrescriberAccount, Account_City, Account_State, Acct_mgr, GG, Account_Dates.  All fields are not necessary.

Bound Column 1

Control Src:  Prescriber
Row Source Prescriber fields are as follows:
Prescriber_Index, Prescriber, ExpDate, AccountIDs, PrescriberID
In the query, AccountIDs field has the following Criteria:  [Forms]![frm_MasterTracker]![cboAccount]

Bound Column 2

Comment: qry_column:

Prescriber  AccountIDs  Prescriber Account
Name        3                 AccountName

This is not what's happening.  What is happening:

Prescriber  AccountIDs  Prescriber Account
Name                            3